# How can I block Apache Ignite message "Possible too long JVM pause" in output console?

Tags: java, logging, ignite

While debugging I'm flooded with this messages. More in general it is something I don't want in my development environment, while it's fine to have it in prod.

How can I disable such messaging?

```
2021-10-13 10:11:48.973  WARN 5072 --- [detector-worker] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal  : Possible too long JVM pause: 1121 milliseconds.
2021-10-13 10:11:50.501  WARN 5072 --- [detector-worker] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal  : Possible too long JVM pause: 1479 milliseconds.
```

Comment: I realized that my breakpoints were stopping all threads - so just configuring the IDE to stop only the current thread is solving the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can see that you have solved your problem, but the question remains relevant so I will answer anyway.

The warnings come from [LongJVMPauseDetector](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/LongJVMPauseDetector.java) and can be suppressed by changing the logging configuration to ERROR for the logger for that class. A better option would be to increase the threshold for when to warn. Set the system property `IGNITE_JVM_PAUSE_DETECTOR_THRESHOLD` to something higher than the default 500 ms, for example 120000 for 120 seconds. That will get rid of the unwanted warnings (unless you pause for more than two minutes, of course).

Comment: Related: Full list of system properties used by Apache Ignite: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteSystemProperties.html